# node_modulesに登録されるモジュール実装を一部変更したい

Tags: node.js, npm

npm install -D でインストールしたmochaを使用しています。
このmochaのコマンドライン、bin/_mochaの一部の挙動に不満があり、現在は手作業でソースコードの一部を書き換えつつ運用し、望みの結果を得ている状況です。
（この変更は現在私が携わっているプロジェクトでのみ有用なもので、GitHubにプルリクエストを送るような性格のものではありません）

しかしこの行為はnpmで提供されるモジュールを破壊しているわけで、できればもっと穏便な方法を使いたいところです。
こういう場合に、なにかいい方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fork しましょう。

[image: fork button]

fork 先で必要な変更を行ったら、`package.json`の mocha の場所を fork にします。

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "mocha": "your-github-name/mocha"
    }
}
```

---

または clone してプライベートのリポジトリに push します。
そして、例えば次のようにします。

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "mocha": "ssh://git@your-repository/mocha.git"
    }
}
```

---

package.json で使える依存モジュールの在処の指定方法は、[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies)を参考にしてください。

Comment: GitHub上のリポジトリを、私的に複製してしまうという方法ですね。自分としてはこれもまた思い切った方法のように見えるのですが、GitHubはこのような使い方（わずかな変更のためにリポジトリを丸ごと複製されてしまうこと）は認めているのでしょうか？

Comment: もちろんです。むしろ気軽な fork が推奨されているからこそ、ページの一番上に fork ボタンがあるのです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらを試して見ます。